# Dagger 2 - Why is this a dependency cycle?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger, dagger-2

I'm trying to inject the application's `Context` into 2 other objects, an `AuthManager` and an `ApiClient`.

Both of them depends on said context, and the `ApiClient` depends on the `AuthManager`. Why is this a dependency cycle, if `Context` doesn't have a reference to the others 2? can this be solved?

**EDIT:** here is some code

```
@Module
public class AppModule {

    private final Application application;

    public AppModule(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Provides @Singleton
    Context provideApplicationContext() {
         return this.application;
    }
}


@Module
public class NetworkModule {

    @Provides @Singleton
    public AuthManager providesAuthManager(AuthManager manager) {
        return manager;
    }

    @Provides @Singleton
    public ApiClient providesApiClient(ApiClientFactory factory) {
        return factory.create();
    }
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, NetworkModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    void inject(BaseActivity activity);

    // Exported for child-components
    Context context();
    ApiClient apiClient();
    AuthManager authManager();
}
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```
@Provides @Singleton
public AuthManager providesAuthManager(AuthManager manager) {
    return manager;
}
```

Your `providesAuthManager` method which provides an `AuthManager` depends on an `AuthManager`.

There's your cycle :)

Comment: It helps to add any error messages you get to the question. In this case, you've interpreted the error message the wrong way, making it harder for us to help :)

Comment: I see. It seems I misunderstood the coffee maker example, as I thougt by placing the `AuthManager` as a local param, dagger would auto-inject to it. Seems like the right way is to set the `Context` as the local param. Thanks :)

Comment: This answer prompted me to double check a provides method and saved me hours of effort tracking down something caused by a simple typo. Thanks!

Comment: I think what you are looking for is @Bind

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `providesAuthManager` method and add `@Inject` in your AuthManager Constructor.

Comment: This lead to other error: "...cannot be provided without @Provide annotated-method"